# For vectors in an Inner product space, would this be a valid proof for the triangle inequality?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, inner-products

Let $V$ be an inner product space.
Show that
$$||x + y|| ≤ ||x|| + ||y||$$
for all x, y ∈ V

---

By Pythagoras’ Theorem
$$||x + y||^2 = ||x||^2 + ||y||^2$$

$$||x + y||^2 = (||x|| + ||y||)^2-2||x||||y||$$
$$||x + y||^2 \leq (||x|| + ||y||)^2$$
$$||x + y|| \leq ||x|| + ||y||$$

---

The proof in our course uses Cacuhy-Schwarz Inequality. But I want to know if this is a valid proofing method?

**EDIT**:ok I see the issue now. As x and y might not be orthogonal, we cannot use Pythagoras's here. Thank you all.

Comment: $\|x + y\|^2 = \|x\|^2 + \|y\|^2$ isn't true in general.

Comment: So this would work only if x and y are orthogonal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(\|x\|+\|y\|)^2=\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2+2\|x\|\|y\|\ge \|x\|^2+\|y\|^2+2<x,y>=\|x+y\|^2.$ Hence we have the triangular inequality.

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not correct. You can only apply Pythagoras' theorem if $x$ and $y$ are orthogonal.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Pythagoras because that doesn't apply to arbitrary vectors. The triangle inequality is equivalent, by squaring, to $$\Vert x+y\Vert^2\le\Vert x\Vert^2+\Vert y\Vert^2+2\Vert x\Vert\Vert y\Vert,$$and from $\Vert u\Vert^2=\langle u|u\rangle$ this reduces to $\langle x,\,y\rangle+\langle y,\,x\rangle\le2\Vert x\Vert \Vert y\Vert$. So you'll have to use Cauchy-Schwarz or something close to it to finish the proof for general $x,\,y\in V$.